# show gridview headers when binding the gridview with a list

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I would like to show headers of a gridview which contains no data:

```
List<myData> datas = new List<myData>();

Gridview1.DataSource = datas.ToArray();
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

But then headers will be not shown. How can I show the headers in case the datas is empty?

I am still using .NET Framework 2.0, the server does not support .NET 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

[Show Grid view header and footer when the grid view is empty (with Generic List)](http://blog.waleedmohamed.net/2009/04/show-grid-view-header-and-footer-when.html)

from your code I think the `.ToArray()` call is not needed, a GridView should be able to bind also to the List directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GridView [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx) to display the headers when there's no data.

example:

```
<asp:GridView>
     <emptydatatemplate>

      <table><tr><td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td><td>Header 3</td><td>Header 4</td></tr></table>
    </emptydatatemplate> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this...

```
//Check to see if we get rows back, if we do just bind.

if (grdview.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    grdview.DataSource = dtFunding;
    grdview.DataBind();
}
else
{
  //Other wise add a emtpy "New Row" to the datatable and then hide it after binding.

     grdview.Rows.Add(grdview.NewRow());
     grdview.DataSource = dtFunding;
     grdview.DataBind();
     grdview.Rows[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: @DavidePiras if he use Asp.net 4.0 this is best solution .... ASP.Net 4.0 added the boolean ShowHeaderWhenEmpty property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty.aspx

Comment: my server does not support asp.net 4.0 :(